# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException "android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS"

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to guide my users to the battery optimizations activity and it seems to be working for most except for some Samsung phones with Android 6 where I get:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS }
```

This is what I am using to launch it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

Any idea what I should be launching on those phones?

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely, there is nothing to launch. You may have better luck by not using that string literal, but rather referring to `Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS`. That way, if Samsung changed both the Settings app *and* the literal, you might have something that works.

Comment: This field is actually a static final field, so the string constant will be inlined, no matter if it is a literal or a field access.

Comment: same issue: Samsung Galaxy A7 and Galaxy S5 Dual SIM (both 6.0.1 Android)

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using `Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS` but still..

Answer (score -2):

**Use below code to check whether your app already ignored for battery optimization and if yes then show popup to enable the same.**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName())) {

                Intent batterySaverIntent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, Uri.parse("package:"+getPackageName()));
                startActivity(batterySaverIntent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This also doesn't work on some Samsungs, and you must also hold `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission you didn't mentioned.