# How solve a Fatal Exception in android.content.ActivityNotFoundException Error

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

I'm trying to guide my users to the battery optimizations activity and it seems to be working for most except for some Samsung phones with Android 6 where I get

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS }
```

This error Showed in OPPO F3 Mobiles,
This is what I am using to launch it

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

Any idea what I should be launching on those phones?

Thanks.

Comment: By caching `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Comment: Can you try the answer given on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909119/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-android-settings-ignore-battery-optim

Comment: oppo and vivo mobiles only not working

Comment: Already tried this solution @Bentaye

Comment: **android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS }** this error showing @Bentaye

Answer (score 1):

On some devices this activity may not exist, because of custom firmware.

You can check your intent by using this method:

```
private static boolean isIntentAvailable(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
    return context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0;
}
```

And when you do startActivity do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS");
if (isIntentAvailable(this, intent)) {
     startActivity(intent);
} else {
     // Do something else
}
```

Or catch your exception.
Or find these custom activities on problem devices and call them.

Comment: how to include this method in my activity, please explain thet

Comment: Just copy this method and paste in your activity, after that you can use this method in your code like I wrote @RameshYogu

Comment: thank you ,But not working Same Error displayed in oppo  mobile @shmakova